# Tension on pulleys Physics Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics, equilibrium

Collar A is connected to a 50lb load on a frictionless horizontal rod. Determine magnitude of P to maintain equilibrium when x=4.5.

[image]

Im confused on the concept of Tension

I originally got the answer 11.25 lb like the images below but my solution manual is different.
[image]

The solution manual says:

$$\tan \alpha= 20/4.5 = 77.3 d^\circ$$

sum of F sub X=0 
$$-P + T \cos 77.3 $$
$$P= 50lb (cos 77.3)$$
$$= 10.98lb$$

(answer manual)

Is this because the tension in the rope is equivalent to the mass of the hanging weight? Is there a way to solve for 10.98lb using method like the one below ...i.e. adding the vector components and solving for the unknowns? confused especially on how the solution manual is using 50lb for magnitude of T and when using vector addition getting the 11 so lbs. Thanks!

but this one below is what makes sense to me.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/yci9.png/  
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/y53e.png/

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do when you write $\sin 77.32/50 = \sin 12.68/P$?

Answer (score 0):

Tension in AB is 50lb.Since the collar cannot move vertically, the     vertical component of tension will be provided by the rod. Force P sho}uld cancel the horizontal component of tension.Therefore $p=50\cos\left(77.3^{\;\mathrm{o}}\right)$